# 'OpenFileDialog' crashes randomly and never works again until a windows reset

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-10

There's a small probability `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()` doesn't generate a new window and my program is dead. After one crash, it happens always. Restarting the program doesn't solve the problem. The task manager doesn't respond as well so I can't check what causes the crash. The only thing I can do is to restart windows. Sometimes my operations after the crash cause windows to restart 'explorer.exe' (judging from the reset of the taskbar) and I'm able to use `OpenFileDialog` again.

I'm using WIN10 (corrected, not WIN7)/VS2022(corrected, not 2023) Community/C#/.NET Framework 4. When I was using C++/Cli, I found a solution by adding `.ShowHelp = true` which avoided such crashes. But it doesn't work in C#.

```
namespace name1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        void ClickLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog Open1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            Open1.Title = "Select the File to Load";
            Open1.InitialDirectory = StringInitialPath;
            Open1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt|All files|*.*";
            Open1.ShowHelp = true;  //avoid crash for C++/Cli, but not here
            if (Open1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  //it crashes right here
            {
                ......
            }
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

What's the cause of this problem and how can I avoid it?

Edit:
[Adding a screenshot for shell extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4zpw.jpg)

Comment: "WIN7/VS2023 Community" that's an interesting combination. Win7 went out of support a few years ago and now has some serious security vulnerabilities, have you considered upgrading to Win10 or 11? Is your .NET at least up to date?

Comment: @Charlieface It's my mistake. I confused the system on the company computer with the one at home. On my personal computer I'm still using VS2010 Express. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Have you tried running that on a different computer? If it only happens at one place, then maybe something on that machine is the issue.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel It will have to wait until my program is used in work. Simply repeating clicks doesn't reproduce the problem even on my computer so it's hard to test it on another. It may need the program to be busy, have been busy or active for a long time, I don't really know. Until then, I can only hope it's a known issue which someone can help me with.

Comment: You may have a rogue Shell extension  that's causing the problem -- There's no 2023 version of VS -- If you really have a 2010 version of VS in a machine, it's time to update

Comment: Yeah, my money's on a shell extension.

Comment: @Jimi Another mistake of mine, it's 2022. I haven't implemented external dlls. The complete codes are too many so I don't know which parts to upload. A possible suspect is the COM port and a thread to poll its received data. Does it work as a shell extension?

Comment: It's not about your code, I mean Shell Extensions installed in the System. When you create a new Open/Save FileDialog (System Shell stuff), a number of libraries are loaded into your Process. Get [SysInternal's AutoRuns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and/or [NirSoft's ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to find out (there's usually no need to disable Microsoft's Shell Extensions)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the advice. It's totally possible. The company computer has installed lots of stuff I cannot turn off.

Comment: I would suggest you speak to your IT department and possibly your management. If they are using bad Shell extensions, and Windows 7, they need to be sacked pronto.

Comment: @Jimi I had a check for shell extensions but found nothing suspicious. I added a screenshot in my question. Only 'windows shell common dll' is available. The problem still happens when I don't expect it. And when it happens, windows explorer cannot open new windows as well. The opened windows cannot switch to other folders. But this problem is only triggered by OpenFileDialog(or perhaps SaveFileDialog as well).